# Commenting out Ember.Select breaks the page, gives an error

Tags: ember.js

When I remove this code from template of ember-cli project

```
{{view Ember.Select
                    class="form-control"
                    viewName="list"
                    content=availableList
                    optionValuePath="content.value"
                    optionLabelPath="content.label"
                    value=selectedList
                    prompt="Select a list item"
                }}
```

I get the following error in browser console, and it breaks everything.

```
TypeError: this.$(...)[0] is undefined
    var selectedIndex = this.$()[0].selectedIndex,
```

Any idea why this is happening, I couldn't find any linking too. Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was such a silly mistake. The commenting of Handlebar code is done by

```
{{!-- --}}
```

I was doing `<!-- -->` and thus the error.

Comment: Thought so ^^ glad you got it sorted.